# How to send an image via HTTP using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, http

I'm developping a kind of API with NodeJS.

I need to do a kind of getImage that returns an image corresponding to the name into the url (ex: localhost:8080/getImage/myImg).

I found many tutorials on the internet but the problem is I mustn't use the writeFile and readFile from FS, because my images are stored into an Array with other JSON informations. The images that I'm storing are sent by another API in tomCat and my job is to limitate the calls to the tomCat API by setting up a NodeJS API.

My question is how to send an image stored into a variable/array/json ?

I tried the code below but when I'm going to localhost:8080/getImage/myImg, the code is executed, but nothing is returned.
I didn't try to use a kind of tmp folder where I'm sotring images because I'm working on a big product and if I can limitate access to the disk it would be great.

```
app.get('/getImage/:name', (req, res) => {
  imagesArray.forEach( (image) => {
    if(req.params.name === image.small_image_name) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'})
      res.end(image.small_image, 'binary')
    } else if (req.params.name === image.full_image_name) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'})
      res.end(image.full_image, 'binary')
    }
  })
})
```

The thing I would make is : you do an http request to the url with an image name as parameter, to "download" the image and change the background of an element displayed on my main page.

Thank you for your future answers.
have a nice day !

Comment: Your loop is dangerous, cause depending on the arrays contents it might never end the reuqest, or it might call ˋ.endˋ multiple times wich obviously won't work too. You should replace that forEach with a ˋ.findˋ that finds the image to send, then ˋ.endˋonce. Then you will probably find out that none of the images got found, thus nothing was returned

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you wish, I'm assuming that the image.small_image and image.full_image contain Buffer objects with the image data. If the image data is stored as a byte array or a base64 string, this is easy to convert to a buffer.

```
app.get('/getImage/:name', (req, res) => {
    const image = imagesArray.find(image => (req.params.name === image.small_image_name || req.params.name === image.full_image_name));

    if (!image) {
        res.status(404).send("Image not found");
        return;
    }

    const imageBuffer = (req.params.name === image.small_image_name) ? image.small_image: image.full_image;
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'image/jpeg' })
    res.end(imageBuffer, 'binary')
});
```

I'm using port 3000 on my local machine, so the request url will look like:

```
http://localhost:3000/getImage/test.jpg
```

Another approach is to create a map of your images beforehand, this will increase retrieval efficiency. Be aware this could increase the memory requirement of the process.

```
const imageMap = imagesArray.reduce((map, image) => { 
    map[image.small_image_name] = { name: image.small_image_name, data: image.small_image };
    map[image.full_image_name] = { name: image.full_image_name, data: image.full_image };
    return map;
}, {});

app.get('/getImage/:name', (req, res) => {
    const image = imageMap[req.params.name];
    if (!image) {
        res.status(404).send("Image not found");
        return;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'image/jpeg' })
    res.end(image.data, 'binary')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the way I'm doing the request on the tomCat API is the following one

```
http.get('http://10.10.0.8:8080/CWallWeb/ajax/getImage.jsp?f=' + body.data[i].urlPreviewPath + '&d=' + date, res => {
    let body = ''

    res.on('data', data => {
        body += data
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        small_image = body
    });
});
```

It is clearly not a buffer it is a string, how can I convert the result of the http request to a buffer?